# how to call default blueprint actions in a custom overridden one?

Tags: sails.js

SailsJS provides default blueprint actions, such as find, update, create, etc.

I need to override some of them to suit particular business purposes. However, I would like to add to them, instead of simply override them. How to call the default blueprint actions in the overriding action.

For example, update can update the record of a model.

```
update
```

I want to have update do more, besides updating the record of a model. In my custom update method, I do not want to duplicate default update. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy everything from

```
PROJECT-ROOT\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\blueprints\actions
```

to

```
PROJECT-ROOT\config\blueprints
```

Make sure findOne.js is lowercase. You will need to modify each one to make reference to the location of `actionUtil.js`. You can now modify these at your hearts content without re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: How to make those overriding actions different for different models?

Comment: It depends. If you have vast differences between models, then you probably don't want to use blueprints at all. In your controller you can just add a single method to overwrite  a single action and leave the rest untouched. So for User model, I could create an "update" method on that controller and it will overwrite just that blueprint and leave the rest intact. However, if your differences are small, then you can identify you models inside the blueprint files and make adjustments as necessary.

Comment: I've tried your solution but couldn't make it work. During the lift procedure, I got the error `A hook ('userconfig') failed to load!`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mphasize/e9ed62f9d139d2152445 beforeBlueprint policy can make sense

Answer (score 10):

I just came across the same issue and found a different way to fix it. It may help in the future if someone has the same problem. What I finally did was to re-write the action in the controller, in my case it was `add` and then, after doing some stuff inside, called the default blueprint's action. 
So, my code looks like below:

```
add: function (req, res) {
    if (xxx) {
        // I need to do something only when the condition above is met
        Section.count({xxx: xxx)}).exec(function (error, count) {
            if (error) {
                return res.json(500, {error: 'There was an error while trying to run query'});
            }
            //I do what I have to do
            return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.add(req, res);
        });
    } else {
        //I just return the default blueprint's action
        return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.add(req, res);
    }
}
```

So, basically, default blueprint functions are stored in:
`sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware`

Comment: This answered the question for me. Thanks

Comment: thumbs for that you are a champ :)

Comment: Take into account all functions in `sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware` have lowercase names (eg `findone`)

Comment: Supposed that in my controller I call ```sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.findone(req, res);```  how can I get the model object **before** is sent back to the client?

Comment: ```sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware``` doesn't seem to have any of those(find, findone, findOne etc.). Any idea where they have been moved? The workaround is to ```require(`${sails.config.appPath}/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/${action}`)```, but not ideal at all...

Comment: @Mindastic I would also love to know where sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware has gone - I only get errors like `sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.create is not a function`

Comment: I am sorry but about 5 years ago was the last time I used sails. I won't be able to help with this one.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) in sailsjs. So for example, you can use `beforeUpdate` or `beforeCreate` lifecycle callback to do more in the model:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
      required: true,
      columnName: 'encrypted_password'
    }

  },


  // Lifecycle Callbacks
  beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {

    // Encrypt password
    bcrypt.hash(values.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
      if(err) return cb(err);
      values.password = hash;
      //calling cb() with an argument returns an error. Useful for canceling the entire operation if some criteria fails.
      cb();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried beforeUpdate lifecycle callback. But when I post to a model, e.g. POST /abc where Abc is the model, beforeUpdate is also trigger. Why is that?

Comment: I think it shouldn't. Do you also have a `beforeCreate` callback? Perhaps you're editing and saving a model there without using the callback provided which is triggering `beforeUpdate`?