# Calling the default blueprint action inside a customized action?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to call the default blueprint action inside a customized action. How can I do this?

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204247/how-to-call-default-blueprint-actions-in-a-custom-overridden-one), I tried to use this: `sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.update(this.req, this.res);`
inside my custom update action

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    try {
        sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.update(this.req, this.res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    return exits.success();
}
```

but it gets an error: `TypeError: sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.update is not a function`

Then I tried to declare: `let update = require('sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/update');`
and call

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    update(this.req, this.res);
    return exits.success();
}
```

But without success.

I'm using Sails.JS v1.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that new blueprints can't be created, but only overridden. So to make a custom blueprint, it has to take over the name of an existing one.